# PHP class sessions

Tags: php, class, session

I'm sorry, I followed WikiHow steps (link is down there) and I made everything but here is the problem:

My index.php contains password input.

```
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
            {
                require('session.class.php');
                if(hash('sha256', $_POST['pass']) == hash('sha256', 'password123'))
                {
                        $session = new session();
                        $session->start_session('_s', false);
                        $_SESSION['namesession'] = 'something';
                        header(location: /mama.php);

                }
                else
                {
                        echo "<font color='#FF0000'>Wrong password!</font>";
                }
    }
```

I don't understand how to put session check on other pages. Other words:
How to put inside if password is correct, you can stay on mama.php page..

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Session-Management-System-in-PHP-and-MySQL#Create_session.class.php_file_sub

Comment: I wouldn't really trust a WikiHow guide, especially when they are trying to enter PHP code into an SQL query window.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a session, it must be at the very beginning of your code, before any HTML or text is sent.

So if you want to check the post data put the if statement after the session_start().